# How to fix Angular CLI forcing scss over sass?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

In my projects I usually want to take advantage of the .sass syntax.
So I created a project like so:

```
ng new myProject --style=sass
```

But the result was that all stylesheets including the base styles file had .scss extension.
Now of course I tried correcting that using cli:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext sass
```

and directly manually changing stuff in the angular.json:

```
"schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        }
      }
```

But with no success. Every new component's styles file I generate comes with 
.scss extension.
How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your schematics need to use `styleext` instead of `style`.

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
  "styleext": "scss"
}
```

`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss` is going to set your global default which should add an entry to the bottom of your `angular.json` file like so:

```
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "styleext": "sass"
  }
}
```

However, if you have the `defaultProject` specified, any schematics inside of here will probably override. So inside of your default project in the angular.json file, update that `style` property in the schematics to `styleext`:

```
"projects": {
  "my-project": {
    ...
    "schematics": {
      "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "styleext": "scss"
    ...
```

---

**After more research**
It seems like you can change your CLI version to an older version, or wait for an update that is on the way (fix merged yesterday). Sass ext support was dropped [noted in this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13574), but it seems to have been re-added [noted in this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13739).

Comment: Unfortunately changing style to styleext didn't solve the problem. The cli command didn't work either. I dry ran when generating a new component, and the styles file comes with scss extention. The same behavior persists even after reboot

Comment: Updated the response to give you more info on the issue

Comment: Thanks for your research. Much appreciated!

Comment: the problem is solved in the latest release of Angular (7.2.11)!